# Discriminate between empty object type and other concrete types

Tags: typescript

All of this compiles without error:

```
interface Empty { }
interface MaybeEmpty { a?: number; }

var one: Object = 20;
var two: Empty = 21;
var three: {} = 22;
var four: MaybeEmpty = 23;
```

Is there a way to define a type with all optional properties, but which nevertheless discriminates against non-object types like `string`, `number`, and `boolean`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update for TS2.4+, there is now [weak type detection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#weak-type-detection) which will prevent assigning to all-optional-property types like `MaybeEmpty` if there are no overlapping properties, so `var four: MaybeEmpty = 23` is now not permitted.

---

Update for TS2.2+, there is now an [`object`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type) type which specifically excludes primitives.  Object-like types using curly braces like `{}` or `{ a?: number }` are still compatible with primitives, as mentioned below.

---

Original answer:

No.

The root problem is that JavaScript often treats primitive values as if they were their Object-typed equivalents (`String`/`Number`/etc) when used in a context where an object is required (e.g. property access).

TypeScript models this using the *"apparent type"* whereby objects of a primitive type appear to have the members of their corresponding Object types. This is because, intuitively, code like this *should* compile without error:

```
function fn(x: { toString(): string }) { /* ... */ }
fn(32); // Should be OK because (32).toString() is OK
fn('foo'); // Should be OK because ('foo').toString() is OK
```

It's a small step to this code:

```
function fn(x: { toString(): string; other?: whatever; }) { /* ... */ }
fn(32); // Should be OK
fn('foo'); // Should be OK
```

And another small step to this code:

```
function fn(x: { other?: whatever; }) { /* ... */ }
fn(32); // OK, I guess?
fn('foo'); // OK, I guess?
```

There's an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/391) tracking the general problem that an interface with all optional properties is effectively never the source of an error when assigning *to* it. It's a very hard thing to spec.

Comment: Updated this answer for `object` and weak type detection, hope that's okay with you.

Answer (score 1):

Necromancing.
Had this problem myselfs. 
This is actually possible in TypeScript 2.2+.

You need to add & object to your type-definition

e.g.

```
var varname: YourInterface & object = something;
```

in your case:

```
interface Empty { }
interface MaybeEmpty { a?: number; }
interface MaybeEmptyAndMore { a?: number; [x:string]: any; }


var one: Object = 20;
var two: Empty = 21;
var three: {} = 22;
var four: MaybeEmpty & object = 23;
var foura: MaybeEmpty & object = {};
var fourb: MaybeEmpty & object = { a: "23"};
var fourc: MaybeEmpty & object = { abc: "23"};
var fourd: MaybeEmptyAndMore & object = { abc: "123", def: "456" };
```

By the way, if it could be a string or an interface (object), then:

```
obj: string | YourInterface & object
```

e.g.

```
class Cookie
{
    constructor(nameOrSettings: string | ICookieSettings  & object )
    {
        if(typeof(nameOrSettings)  === 'string')
        { do_something();}
        else if(typeof(nameOrSettings) === 'object')
        {
             var obj:ICookieSettings = <ICookieSettings><any>nameOrSettings;
        }
        else throw TypeError("foo");
    }
}
```