# TypeScript: How to limit interface to variable of type object?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have the following TypeScript interface

```
interface ICookieOptions
{
    name?:string;
    value?:string;
    secure?:boolean;
    session?: boolean;
    sameSite?: boolean;
}
```

and the following class

```
class Cookie
{
     constructor(nameOrOptions: string | ICookieOptions)
     { [...]}
}
```

now I can do the following:

```
var testOptions = 
    {
        name:"abc",
        value:"def"
        secure: false,
        session: true,
        sameSite: true
    };    
new Cookie(testOptions);
new Cookie(123);
```

and get no error. 
I figured this is because all elements in ICookieOptions are optional. 
And as soon as i remove the ? in name?, it outputs an error on the constructor with a number.

Now: How can I have ALL elements of ICookieOptions as optional, and restrict 
 ICookieOptions to variables of type "object" (not number, boolean, etc.) ?

Comment: I've seen this question asked before, but I cannot find it to use it as a dupe target. However, this should go some way to answering your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28122837/6680611

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, found the answer myselfs. 
One needs to specify `& object` in the type definition :

```
class Cookie
{
     constructor(nameOrOptions: string | ICookieOptions & object)
     { [...]}
}
```

requires TypeScript v2.2+